# When making POST request with Nodejs, how to get content length of request payload?

Tags: node.js, http, express, httprequest

I'm making a http request to remote API using Nodejs, using the request library.

The request payload is a plain old JavaScript object.

I need to set content-length header on the request, but I'm not sure how to get this value?

Previously I have used Buffer.byteLenth(requestPayload), but does not work with objects.

Comment: Surely the `request` module is setting this already?  If not, I'd file a bug report, as it's not like it's going to stream the JSON output.  (And, that is what you're sending... you can send a JavaScript object as-is, it has to get serialized somehow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're relying on `request` to turn an object into a JSON serialization, then the answer simply is 'don't'. The only way to predict the size is to serialize it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Evert, you're completely right.  In the end we just removed the requirements for the client to set the content-length header in the request, much simpler..